# What Jenkins loggers do you usually have enabled?

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins isn't really good at telling by default what it does and I'm curious what are people using to log in their day to day jenkins master log.

Comment: I usually only set additional [loggers](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logger+Configuration) when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

There are some Jenkins instances running at our servers, but there is nothing special enabled for the production environment.

Different [log levels](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logger+Configuration) will be set based on plugins or features not working like expected.

You do better if you enable only debug logging, if you need to.